# Fixing an audio cassette recording, due to "stretched tape"?

Tags: audio, mp3

I was able to convert audio cassette to mp3 form, using a walkman style device with built in mp3 conversion, but when I go to listen to the audio, the sound is a little distorted. I am suspecting this is because the tape stretched over time or something equivalent has happened to it. I am sure there is a term for this issue, but I wasn't able to find a good definition.

Is the any tool or process that can help deal with an audio recording of such a source? Ideally for Linux or macOS.

Comment: Short of cutting out the stretched section, taping the tape's two ends together with scotch tape, the only other way [AFAIK] would be to use audio editing software _(Adobe Audition and similar)_ to try and clean up the signal _(keep in mind, FLAC is preferable, with 320kbps CBR MP3s being the minimum that should be used, especially when trying to salvage a signal, as you want the least amount of information removed from the signal when encoding [compression removes data from the signal])_

Comment: Before you can fix any audio, you need to identify **exactly** what needs fixing. "distortion, tape stretch *or something* really doesn't help us to help you. If you do have tape-stretch, wow or flutter, then it can be fixed, but it's about the most expensive fix you could imagine. Only one app exists that can do it & it costs $3790 https://www.celemony.com/en/capstan - so it's probably best if you do correctly identify your issue first ;) BTW, don't use mp3 if your audio needs work, record at 24-bit WAV, downsample once it's fixed.